# Deep comparison between objects

Tags: javascript

I'm studying Javascript and I came across this exercise, a "deepEqual" function that I should have written, which I couldn't solve and even after I saw the solution I still don't quite understand it. I don't understand the `for` loop, in particular the `!deepEqual(a[key], b[key]))` part. Why can I not just say `(keysA[key] !== keysB[key])` or `(a[key] !== b[key])`? What I read from this line is that "if the values of the keys in the objects `a` and `b` are not present in `deepEqual` then `return false`", but the values are there, they exist and I don't see where is the comparison between them. Obviously I'm wrong but this is my understanding of the code. Please enlighten me.

```js
function deepEqual(a, b) {
  if (a === b) return true;

  if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
      b == null || typeof b != "object") return false;

  let keysA = Object.keys(a), keysB = Object.keys(b);

  if (keysA.length != keysB.length) return false;

  for (let key of keysA) {
    if (!keysB.includes(key) || !deepEqual(a[key], b[key])) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

let obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
// → true
```

Comment: Do you know what *recursion* is?

Comment: Do you know what *nested objects* mean?

Comment: I know what recursion and nested objects are. I just don't really know how to work with them, especially with recursion it's twisting my brain every time I see a recursive function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't say `a[key] != b[key]` because these values can be objects. And in order to compare objects, you have to compare their contents recursively -- that's the whole reason you had to write this `deepEqual()` function in the first place.

The line:

```
    if (!keysB.includes(key) || !deepEqual(a[key], b[key])) return false;
```

means that we return `false` if `b` doesn't have `key` as a property, or if recursing into the `key` property of both objects is not equal.

If that key does exist, and the nested objects are equal, we continue the loop with the next key.

The actual comparison at the root of the recursion happens on the first line:

```
if (a === b) return true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the recursing part, but even then I don't see where is the computer checking if the nested objects are equal or not, I mean there is no statement like `a[key] === b[key]` or something like that. So `!deepEqual(a[key], b[key]))` the computer knows he needs to recurse, look if they exist, and now where is the comparison? This is what I miss.

Comment: `deepEqual()` is performing the comparison.

Comment: The comparison is in the test `if (a === b)`. All the rest is handling the case where the arguments are not identical, and then we recurse into them if they're objects.

Comment: If I understood correctly then, I cannot directly state `a[key] !== b[key]` because the computer doesn't know their type yet. So it will run once, understand they are objects and then after the recursion will have memorised that they are objects, and only then can go on with the `a ===  b` comparison? Don't know if it's correct what I said but it actually makes more sense to me now. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: It has nothing to do with the type. Try `{a: 1} !== {a: 1}`. It will say that they're not equal.

Comment: The computer knows the types of everything. But it doesn't compare objects recursively, the way `deepEqual()` does.

Comment: Ok then, my new theory is: in the moment I call `!deepEqual(a[key], b[key])`, it's like I'm assigning a new value to `a` and `b` and this value is the value of `key`, and then the comparison `a === b` works, because it's comparing single values? Because like you showed me, two objects will never result being the same objects, even if they look the same. I think I get it now.

Comment: Yes, that's how recursion works. The next call sets `a` to `a[key]` and `b` to `b[key]`.